# Getting the load time of each iframe with multiple sources

Tags: javascript

I am trying to get the loadtime of each iframe, and then display the time. Here is the code i currently have (without the loading time calculations):

```
<iframe id="1"  width="100" height="100" src=""></iframe>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){   
    var array = ['http://www.example1.com', 'http://www.example2.com', 'http://www.example3.com'];
    $('#1').on('load', function() {                 
       $('#1').attr('src', array.pop());             
    }).attr('src', array.pop());
});
</script>
```

It puts links from an array into an iframe, loading each iframe one after another.

This is how i used to do get loading time before:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
beforeload = (new Date()).getTime();
function pageloadingtime(i)
{

    var afterload = (new Date()).getTime();
    var seconds = (afterload-beforeload)/1000;
    document.getElementById("loadingtime"+i).innerHTML = seconds;
}
</script>
```

This method didnt work for me because it loaded all the iframes at the same time, instead of loading one by one.

How do i use the 2nd codes methods of counting and displaying the loadtimes of iframes, in the 1st code?

Comment: Not an answer, but if you only need to know, how long it takes to load each `iframe`, you can check it at `Net` tab of the DevTools.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
var array = ['http://www.example1.com', 'http://www.example2.com', 'http://www.example3.com'];
var beforeLoad = (new Date()).getTime();
var loadTimes = [];
$('#1').on('load', function() {
   loadTimes.push((new Date()).getTime());                  
   $('#1').attr('src', array.pop());
    if (array.length === 0) { 
        $.each(loadTimes, function(index, value) {
           alert(value - beforeLoad); 
        });
    }
}).attr('src', array.pop());
});
```

*sidenote*
You have to be sure you can access the websites you are checking by an iframe because most websites nowadays disallow iframes.
if you still want to measure loads without iframes and use javascript you can perhaps use `$.get` requests to imitate the same thing.