# How can I use google analytics user timings to track embedded iframe load times?

Tags: iframe, google-analytics, drupal-7, event-tracking

I would like to setup a way to track embedded iframe load times for a (drupal 7) site, using google analytics, preferably via events sent to the user timing report. The iframes embedded into our site from a variety of sources including sites like twitter, youtube, streamable, etc.

My thought is to automatically calculate the load time for all iframes embedded into our content, then use a data layer push to send the timing event to google analytics.

I know how to create the data layer push and send the timing event to GA, but I'm not sure of the best way to automatically detect the iframe, track it's load time, and define a "timingLabel" to indicate the source of the iframe.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use both JS and Drupal Ajax to achieve this. Place this JS ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15052549/getting-the-load-time-of-each-iframe-with-multiple-sources)) in page.tpl.php or in the common js like main.js

Now after calculating the time you need to make an ajax call to Drupal to record the timing in database if required or you can send directly to GA.